# Weird popup ads from Stack Overflow sites

Tags: support, advertising

I am not sure if this is a browser issue or Stack Overflow is spamming ads, but while clicking on a link or random place I get these popups for "http://bellevueavenue.us/". At first I thought this is an extension causing it but I don't have unknown extensions installed.

Can anybody from Stack Overflow confirm if these are implemented ads?

I am on Chrome and here are the extensions that I am using:

1. Google Docs
2. Google Sheets
3. Google Slides
4. Hangouts
5. JSONView

PS: The popup appears when I click somewhere after a full page load, if the clicked area is not a link. I've checked Chrome network activity when the popup appears, and it says something like *keyboard-shortcut-en.js request is made.*

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you tried with different browser? I think Chrome(may be all browsers) affected by a virus.May be that virus check what site you visit most or another rule which fits for SO and show ads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it happens these popups kept coming after everything I tried and these were super annoying popups so I had to debug many non-https urls to figure what was causing it because all of my plugins installed were from verified publishers and then I didn't install any unnecessary applications on my system.

So after sometime I still don't understand why google analytics would do such a stupid thing yet with every google analytic driven website these popups occur, they are called **popunders**. If I visit `http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` It gives me non minified code and its the very script causing these popunders, if I visit `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` **https** then it becomes minified complicated script which no longer causes popunders so I had to block google-analytics website on my windows by adding it to `C:/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/DRIVERS/ETC/HOSTS`

both scripts are given here:

**non-https version**

```
function makePopunder(pUrl) {
    var _parent = (top != self && typeof (top["document"]["location"].toString()) === "string") ? top : self;
    var mypopunder = null;
    var pName = (Math["floor"]((Math["random"]() * 1000) + 1));
    var pWidth = window["innerWidth"];
    var pHeight = window["innerHeight"];
    var pPosX = window["screenX"];
    var pPosY = window["screenY"];
    var pWait = 120;
    pWait = (pWait * 1000);
    var pCap = 600000;
    var todayPops = 0;
    var cookie = "_.mypopads";
    var browser = function () {
        var n = navigator["userAgent"]["toLowerCase"]();
        var b = {
            webkit: /webkit/ ["test"](n),
            mozilla: (/mozilla/ ["test"](n)) && (!/(compatible|webkit)/ ["test"](n)),
            chrome: /chrome/ ["test"](n),
            msie: (/msie/ ["test"](n)) && (!/opera/ ["test"](n)),
            firefox: /firefox/ ["test"](n),
            safari: (/safari/ ["test"](n) && !(/chrome/ ["test"](n))),
            opera: /opera/ ["test"](n)
        };
        b["version"] = (b["safari"]) ? (n["match"](/.+(?:ri)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1] : (n["match"](/.+(?:ox|me|ra|ie)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1];
        return b;
    }();

    function isCapped() {
        try {
            todayPops = Math["floor"](document["cookie"]["split"](cookie + "Cap=")[1]["split"](";")[0]);
        } catch (err) {};
        return (pCap <= todayPops || document["cookie"]["indexOf"](cookie + "=") !== -1);
    };

    function doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY) {
        if (isCapped()) {
            return;
        };
        var sOptions = "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=1,width=" + pWidth.toString() + ",height=" + pHeight.toString() + ",screenX=" + pPosX + ",screenY=" + pPosY;
        document["onclick"] = function (e) {
            if (isCapped() || window["pop_clicked"] == 1 || pop_isRightButtonClicked(e)) {
                return;
            };
            window["pop_clicked"] = 1;
            mypopunder = _parent["window"]["open"](pUrl, pName, sOptions);
            if (mypopunder) {
                var now = new Date();
                document["cookie"] = cookie + "=1;expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + pWait))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
                now = new Date();
                document["cookie"] = cookie + "Cap=" + (todayPops + 1) + ";expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + (84600 * 1000)))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
                pop2under();
            };
        };
    };

    function pop2under() {
        try {
            mypopunder["blur"]();
            mypopunder["opener"]["window"]["focus"]();
            window["self"]["window"]["blur"]();
            window["focus"]();
            if (browser["firefox"]) {
                openCloseWindow();
            };
            if (browser["webkit"]) {
                openCloseTab();
            };
        } catch (e) {};
    };

    function openCloseWindow() {
        var ghost = window["open"]("about:blank");
        ghost["focus"]();
        ghost["close"]();
    };

    function openCloseTab() {
        var ghost = document["createElement"]("a");
        ghost["href"] = "about:blank";
        ghost["target"] = "PopHelper";
        document["getElementsByTagName"]("body")[0]["appendChild"](ghost);
        ghost["parentNode"]["removeChild"](ghost);
        var clk = document["createEvent"]("MouseEvents");
        clk["initMouseEvent"]("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
        ghost["dispatchEvent"](clk);
        window["open"]("about:blank", "PopHelper")["close"]();
    };

    function pop_isRightButtonClicked(e) {
        var rightclick = false;
        e = e || window["event"];
        if (e["which"]) {
            rightclick = (e["which"] == 3);
        } else {
            if (e["button"]) {
                rightclick = (e["button"] == 2);
            };
        };
        return rightclick;
    };
    if (isCapped()) {
        return;
    } else {
        doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY);
    };
}
makePopunder("data:text/html;base64,PEhUTUw+DQo8bWV0YSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PSJyZWZyZXNoIiBjb250ZW50PSIwO3VybD1odHRwOi8vZ28uYWQydXAuY29tL2FmdS5waHA/aWQ9MjQ1NzcyIj4NCjwvaHRtbD4NCg0K");
```

**https-version**

```
(function(){var aa=encodeURIComponent,f=window,n=Math;function Pc(a,b){return a.href=b}
var Qc="replace",q="data",m="match",ja="port",u="createElement",id="setAttribute",da="getTime",A="split",B="location",ra="hasOwnProperty",ma="hostname",ga="search",E="protocol",Ab="href",kd="action",G="apply",p="push",h="hash",pa="test",ha="slice",r="cookie",t="indexOf",ia="defaultValue",v="name",y="length",Ga="sendBeacon",z="prototype",la="clientWidth",jd="target",C="call",na="clientHeight",F="substring",oa="navigator",H="join",I="toLowerCase";var $c=function(a){this.w=a||[]};$c[z].set=function(a){this.w[a]=!0};$c[z].encode=function(){for(var a=[],b=0;b<this.w[y];b++)this.w[b]&&(a[n.floor(b/6)]=a[n.floor(b/6)]^1<<b%6);for(b=0;b<a[y];b++)a[b]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_".charAt(a[b]||0);return a[H]("")+"~"};var vd=new $c;function J(a){vd.set(a)}var Nd=function(a,b){var c=new $c(Dd(a));c.set(b);a.set(Gd,c.w)},Td=function(a){a=Dd(a);a=new $c(a);for(var b=vd.w[ha](),c=0;c<a.w[y];c++)b[c]=b[c]||a.w[c];return(new $c(b)).encode()},Dd=function(a){a=a.get(Gd);ka(a)||(a=[]);return a};var ea=function(a){return"function"==typeof a},ka=function(a){return"[object Array]"==Object[z].toString[C](Object(a))},qa=function(a){return void 0!=a&&-1<(a.constructor+"")[t]("String")},D=function(a,b){return 0==a[t](b)},sa=function(a){return a?a[Qc](/^[\s\xa0]+|[\s\xa0]+$/g,""):""},ta=function(a){var b=M[u]("img");b.width=1;b.height=1;b.src=a;return b},ua=function(){},K=function(a){if(aa instanceof Function)return aa(a);J(28);return a},L=function(a,b,c,d){try{a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener(b,
c,!!d):a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("on"+b,c)}catch(e){J(27)}},wa=function(a,b){if(a){var c=M[u]("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.async=!0;c.src=a;b&&(c.id=b);var d=M.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];d.parentNode.insertBefore(c,d)}},Ud=function(){return"https:"==M[B][E]},xa=function(){var a=""+M[B][ma];return 0==a[t]("www.")?a[F](4):a},ya=function(a){var b=M.referrer;if(/^https?:\/\//i[pa](b)){if(a)return b;a="//"+M[B][ma];var c=b[t](a);if(5==c||6==c)if(a=b.charAt(c+a[y]),"/"==a||"?"==a||""==
a||":"==a)return;return b}},za=function(a,b){if(1==b[y]&&null!=b[0]&&"object"===typeof b[0])return b[0];for(var c={},d=n.min(a[y]+1,b[y]),e=0;e<d;e++)if("object"===typeof b[e]){for(var g in b[e])b[e][ra](g)&&(c[g]=b[e][g]);break}else e<a[y]&&(c[a[e]]=b[e]);return c};var ee=function(){this.keys=[];this.values={};this.m={}};ee[z].set=function(a,b,c){this.keys[p](a);c?this.m[":"+a]=b:this.values[":"+a]=b};ee[z].get=function(a){return this.m[ra](":"+a)?this.m[":"+a]:this.values[":"+a]};ee[z].map=function(a){for(var b=0;b<this.keys[y];b++){var c=this.keys[b],d=this.get(c);d&&a(c,d)}};var O=f,M=document,Mc=function(){for(var a=O[oa].userAgent+(M[r]?M[r]:"")+(M.referrer?M.referrer:""),b=a[y],c=O.history[y];0<c;)a+=c--^b++;return La(a)};var Aa=function(a){var b=O._gaUserPrefs;if(b&&b.ioo&&b.ioo()||a&&!0===O["ga-disable-"+a])return!0;try{var c=O.external;if(c&&c._gaUserPrefs&&"oo"==c._gaUserPrefs)return!0}catch(d){}return!1};var Ca=function(a){var b=[],c=M[r][A](";");a=new RegExp("^\\s*"+a+"=\\s*(.*?)\\s*$");for(var d=0;d<c[y];d++){var e=c[d][m](a);e&&b[p](e[1])}return b},zc=function(a,b,c,d,e,g){e=Aa(e)?!1:eb[pa](M[B][ma])||"/"==c&&vc[pa](d)?!1:!0;if(!e)return!1;b&&1200<b[y]&&(b=b[F](0,1200),J(24));c=a+"="+b+"; path="+c+"; ";g&&(c+="expires="+(new Date((new Date)[da]()+g)).toGMTString()+"; ");d&&"none"!=d&&(c+="domain="+d+";");d=M[r];M.cookie=c;if(!(d=d!=M[r]))a:{a=Ca(a);for(d=0;d<a[y];d++)if(b==a[d]){d=!0;break a}d=
!1}return d},Cc=function(a){return K(a)[Qc](/\(/g,"%28")[Qc](/\)/g,"%29")},vc=/^(www\.)?google(\.com?)?(\.[a-z]{2})?$/,eb=/(^|\.)doubleclick\.net$/i;var oc=function(){return(Ba||Ud()?"https:":"http:")+"//www.google-analytics.com"},Da=function(a){this.name="len";this.message=a+"-8192"},ba=function(a,b,c){c=c||ua;if(2036>=b[y])wc(a,b,c);else if(8192>=b[y])x(a,b,c)||wd(a,b,c)||wc(a,b,c);else throw ge("len",b[y]),new Da(b[y]);},wc=function(a,b,c){var d=ta(a+"?"+b);d.onload=d.onerror=function(){d.onload=null;d.onerror=null;c()}},wd=function(a,b,c){var d=O.XMLHttpRequest;if(!d)return!1;var e=new d;if(!("withCredentials"in e))return!1;e.open("POST",
a,!0);e.withCredentials=!0;e.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/plain");e.onreadystatechange=function(){4==e.readyState&&(c(),e=null)};e.send(b);return!0},x=function(a,b,c){return O[oa][Ga]?O[oa][Ga](a,b)?(c(),!0):!1:!1},ge=function(a,b,c){1<=100*n.random()||Aa("?")||(a=["t=error","_e="+a,"_v=j37","sr=1"],b&&a[p]("_f="+b),c&&a[p]("_m="+K(c[F](0,100))),a[p]("aip=1"),a[p]("z="+fe()),wc(oc()+"/collect",a[H]("&"),ua))};var Ha=function(){this.M=[]};Ha[z].add=function(a){this.M[p](a)};Ha[z].D=function(a){try{for(var b=0;b<this.M[y];b++){var c=a.get(this.M[b]);c&&ea(c)&&c[C](O,a)}}catch(d){}b=a.get(Ia);b!=ua&&ea(b)&&(a.set(Ia,ua,!0),setTimeout(b,10))};function Ja(a){if(100!=a.get(Ka)&&La(P(a,Q))%1E4>=100*R(a,Ka))throw"abort";}function Ma(a){if(Aa(P(a,Na)))throw"abort";}function Oa(){var a=M[B][E];if("http:"!=a&&"https:"!=a)throw"abort";}
function Pa(a){try{O[oa][Ga]?J(42):O.XMLHttpRequest&&"withCredentials"in new O.XMLHttpRequest&&J(40)}catch(b){}a.set(ld,Td(a),!0);a.set(Ac,R(a,Ac)+1);var c=[];Qa.map(function(b,e){if(e.F){var g=a.get(b);void 0!=g&&g!=e[ia]&&("boolean"==typeof g&&(g*=1),c[p](e.F+"="+K(""+g)))}});c[p]("z="+Bd());a.set(Ra,c[H]("&"),!0)}
function Sa(a){var b=P(a,gd)||oc()+"/collect",c=P(a,fa);!c&&a.get(Vd)&&(c="beacon");if(c){var d=P(a,Ra),e=a.get(Ia),e=e||ua;"image"==c?wc(b,d,e):"xhr"==c&&wd(b,d,e)||"beacon"==c&&x(b,d,e)||ba(b,d,e)}else ba(b,P(a,Ra),a.get(Ia));a.set(Ia,ua,!0)}function Hc(a){var b=O.gaData;b&&(b.expId&&a.set(Nc,b.expId),b.expVar&&a.set(Oc,b.expVar))}function cd(){if(O[oa]&&"preview"==O[oa].loadPurpose)throw"abort";}function yd(a){var b=O.gaDevIds;ka(b)&&0!=b[y]&&a.set("&did",b[H](","),!0)}
function vb(a){if(!a.get(Na))throw"abort";};var hd=function(){return n.round(2147483647*n.random())},Bd=function(){try{var a=new Uint32Array(1);O.crypto.getRandomValues(a);return a[0]&2147483647}catch(b){return hd()}},fe=hd;function Ta(a){var b=R(a,Ua);500<=b&&J(15);var c=P(a,Va);if("transaction"!=c&&"item"!=c){var c=R(a,Wa),d=(new Date)[da](),e=R(a,Xa);0==e&&a.set(Xa,d);e=n.round(2*(d-e)/1E3);0<e&&(c=n.min(c+e,20),a.set(Xa,d));if(0>=c)throw"abort";a.set(Wa,--c)}a.set(Ua,++b)};var Ya=function(){this.data=new ee},Qa=new ee,Za=[];Ya[z].get=function(a){var b=$a(a),c=this[q].get(a);b&&void 0==c&&(c=ea(b[ia])?b[ia]():b[ia]);return b&&b.Z?b.Z(this,a,c):c};var P=function(a,b){var c=a.get(b);return void 0==c?"":""+c},R=function(a,b){var c=a.get(b);return void 0==c||""===c?0:1*c};Ya[z].set=function(a,b,c){if(a)if("object"==typeof a)for(var d in a)a[ra](d)&&ab(this,d,a[d],c);else ab(this,a,b,c)};
var ab=function(a,b,c,d){if(void 0!=c)switch(b){case Na:wb[pa](c)}var e=$a(b);e&&e.o?e.o(a,b,c,d):a[q].set(b,c,d)},bb=function(a,b,c,d,e){this.name=a;this.F=b;this.Z=d;this.o=e;this.defaultValue=c},$a=function(a){var b=Qa.get(a);if(!b)for(var c=0;c<Za[y];c++){var d=Za[c],e=d[0].exec(a);if(e){b=d[1](e);Qa.set(b[v],b);break}}return b},yc=function(a){var b;Qa.map(function(c,d){d.F==a&&(b=d)});return b&&b[v]},S=function(a,b,c,d,e){a=new bb(a,b,c,d,e);Qa.set(a[v],a);return a[v]},cb=function(a,b){Za[p]([new RegExp("^"+
a+"$"),b])},T=function(a,b,c){return S(a,b,c,void 0,db)},db=function(){};var gb=qa(f.GoogleAnalyticsObject)&&sa(f.GoogleAnalyticsObject)||"ga",Ba=!1,he=S("_br"),hb=T("apiVersion","v"),ib=T("clientVersion","_v");S("anonymizeIp","aip");var jb=S("adSenseId","a"),Va=S("hitType","t"),Ia=S("hitCallback"),Ra=S("hitPayload");S("nonInteraction","ni");S("currencyCode","cu");S("dataSource","ds");var Vd=S("useBeacon",void 0,!1),fa=S("transport");S("sessionControl","sc","");S("sessionGroup","sg");S("queueTime","qt");var Ac=S("_s","_s");S("screenName","cd");
var kb=S("location","dl",""),lb=S("referrer","dr"),mb=S("page","dp","");S("hostname","dh");var nb=S("language","ul"),ob=S("encoding","de");S("title","dt",function(){return M.title||void 0});cb("contentGroup([0-9]+)",function(a){return new bb(a[0],"cg"+a[1])});var pb=S("screenColors","sd"),qb=S("screenResolution","sr"),rb=S("viewportSize","vp"),sb=S("javaEnabled","je"),tb=S("flashVersion","fl");S("campaignId","ci");S("campaignName","cn");S("campaignSource","cs");S("campaignMedium","cm");
S("campaignKeyword","ck");S("campaignContent","cc");var ub=S("eventCategory","ec"),xb=S("eventAction","ea"),yb=S("eventLabel","el"),zb=S("eventValue","ev"),Bb=S("socialNetwork","sn"),Cb=S("socialAction","sa"),Db=S("socialTarget","st"),Eb=S("l1","plt"),Fb=S("l2","pdt"),Gb=S("l3","dns"),Hb=S("l4","rrt"),Ib=S("l5","srt"),Jb=S("l6","tcp"),Kb=S("l7","dit"),Lb=S("l8","clt"),Mb=S("timingCategory","utc"),Nb=S("timingVar","utv"),Ob=S("timingLabel","utl"),Pb=S("timingValue","utt");S("appName","an");
S("appVersion","av","");S("appId","aid","");S("appInstallerId","aiid","");S("exDescription","exd");S("exFatal","exf");var Nc=S("expId","xid"),Oc=S("expVar","xvar"),Rc=S("_utma","_utma"),Sc=S("_utmz","_utmz"),Tc=S("_utmht","_utmht"),Ua=S("_hc",void 0,0),Xa=S("_ti",void 0,0),Wa=S("_to",void 0,20);cb("dimension([0-9]+)",function(a){return new bb(a[0],"cd"+a[1])});cb("metric([0-9]+)",function(a){return new bb(a[0],"cm"+a[1])});S("linkerParam",void 0,void 0,Bc,db);var ld=S("usage","_u"),Gd=S("_um");
S("forceSSL",void 0,void 0,function(){return Ba},function(a,b,c){J(34);Ba=!!c});var ed=S("_j1","jid");cb("\\&(.*)",function(a){var b=new bb(a[0],a[1]),c=yc(a[0][F](1));c&&(b.Z=function(a){return a.get(c)},b.o=function(a,b,g,ca){a.set(c,g,ca)},b.F=void 0);return b});
var Qb=T("_oot"),dd=S("previewTask"),Rb=S("checkProtocolTask"),md=S("validationTask"),Sb=S("checkStorageTask"),Uc=S("historyImportTask"),Tb=S("samplerTask"),Vb=S("_rlt"),Wb=S("buildHitTask"),Xb=S("sendHitTask"),Vc=S("ceTask"),zd=S("devIdTask"),Cd=S("timingTask"),Ld=S("displayFeaturesTask"),V=T("name"),Q=T("clientId","cid"),Ad=S("userId","uid"),Na=T("trackingId","tid"),U=T("cookieName",void 0,"_ga"),W=T("cookieDomain"),Yb=T("cookiePath",void 0,"/"),Zb=T("cookieExpires",void 0,63072E3),$b=T("legacyCookieDomain"),
Wc=T("legacyHistoryImport",void 0,!0),ac=T("storage",void 0,"cookie"),bc=T("allowLinker",void 0,!1),cc=T("allowAnchor",void 0,!0),Ka=T("sampleRate","sf",100),dc=T("siteSpeedSampleRate",void 0,1),ec=T("alwaysSendReferrer",void 0,!1),gd=S("transportUrl"),Md=S("_r","_r");function X(a,b,c,d){b[a]=function(){try{return d&&J(d),c[G](this,arguments)}catch(b){throw ge("exc",a,b&&b[v]),b;}}};var Od=function(a,b,c){this.V=1E4;this.fa=a;this.$=!1;this.B=b;this.ea=c||1},Ed=function(a,b){var c;if(a.fa&&a.$)return 0;a.$=!0;if(b){if(a.B&&R(b,a.B))return R(b,a.B);if(0==b.get(dc))return 0}if(0==a.V)return 0;void 0===c&&(c=Bd());return 0==c%a.V?n.floor(c/a.V)%a.ea+1:0};var ie=new Od(!0,he,7),je=function(a){if(!Ud()&&!Ba){var b=Ed(ie,a);if(b&&!(!O[oa][Ga]&&4<=b&&6>=b)){var c=(new Date).getHours(),d=[Bd(),Bd(),Bd()][H](".");a=(3==b||5==b?"https:":"http:")+"//www.google-analytics.com/collect?z=br.";a+=[b,"A",c,d][H](".");var e=1!=b%3?"https:":"http:",e=e+"//www.google-analytics.com/collect?z=br.",e=e+[b,"B",c,d][H](".");7==b&&(e=e[Qc]("//www.","//ssl."));c=function(){4<=b&&6>=b?O[oa][Ga](e,""):ta(e)};Bd()%2?(ta(a),c()):(c(),ta(a))}}};function fc(){var a,b,c;if((c=(c=O[oa])?c.plugins:null)&&c[y])for(var d=0;d<c[y]&&!b;d++){var e=c[d];-1<e[v][t]("Shockwave Flash")&&(b=e.description)}if(!b)try{a=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7"),b=a.GetVariable("$version")}catch(g){}if(!b)try{a=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6"),b="WIN 6,0,21,0",a.AllowScriptAccess="always",b=a.GetVariable("$version")}catch(ca){}if(!b)try{a=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash"),b=a.GetVariable("$version")}catch(l){}b&&
(a=b[m](/[\d]+/g))&&3<=a[y]&&(b=a[0]+"."+a[1]+" r"+a[2]);return b||void 0};var gc=function(a,b){var c=n.min(R(a,dc),100);if(!(La(P(a,Q))%100>=c)&&(c={},Ec(c)||Fc(c))){var d=c[Eb];void 0==d||Infinity==d||isNaN(d)||(0<d?(Y(c,Gb),Y(c,Jb),Y(c,Ib),Y(c,Fb),Y(c,Hb),Y(c,Kb),Y(c,Lb),b(c)):L(O,"load",function(){gc(a,b)},!1))}},Ec=function(a){var b=O.performance||O.webkitPerformance,b=b&&b.timing;if(!b)return!1;var c=b.navigationStart;if(0==c)return!1;a[Eb]=b.loadEventStart-c;a[Gb]=b.domainLookupEnd-b.domainLookupStart;a[Jb]=b.connectEnd-b.connectStart;a[Ib]=b.responseStart-b.requestStart;
a[Fb]=b.responseEnd-b.responseStart;a[Hb]=b.fetchStart-c;a[Kb]=b.domInteractive-c;a[Lb]=b.domContentLoadedEventStart-c;return!0},Fc=function(a){if(O.top!=O)return!1;var b=O.external,c=b&&b.onloadT;b&&!b.isValidLoadTime&&(c=void 0);2147483648<c&&(c=void 0);0<c&&b.setPageReadyTime();if(void 0==c)return!1;a[Eb]=c;return!0},Y=function(a,b){var c=a[b];if(isNaN(c)||Infinity==c||0>c)a[b]=void 0},Fd=function(a){return function(b){"pageview"!=b.get(Va)||a.I||(a.I=!0,gc(b,function(b){a.send("timing",b)}))}};var hc=!1,mc=function(a){if("cookie"==P(a,ac)){var b=P(a,U),c=nd(a),d=kc(P(a,Yb)),e=lc(P(a,W)),g=1E3*R(a,Zb),ca=P(a,Na);if("auto"!=e)zc(b,c,d,e,ca,g)&&(hc=!0);else{J(32);var l;a:{c=[];e=xa()[A](".");if(4==e[y]&&(l=e[e[y]-1],parseInt(l,10)==l)){l=["none"];break a}for(l=e[y]-2;0<=l;l--)c[p](e[ha](l)[H]("."));c[p]("none");l=c}for(var k=0;k<l[y];k++)if(e=l[k],a[q].set(W,e),c=nd(a),zc(b,c,d,e,ca,g)){hc=!0;return}a[q].set(W,"auto")}}},nc=function(a){if("cookie"==P(a,ac)&&!hc&&(mc(a),!hc))throw"abort";},
Yc=function(a){if(a.get(Wc)){var b=P(a,W),c=P(a,$b)||xa(),d=Xc("__utma",c,b);d&&(J(19),a.set(Tc,(new Date)[da](),!0),a.set(Rc,d.R),(b=Xc("__utmz",c,b))&&d[h]==b[h]&&a.set(Sc,b.R))}},nd=function(a){var b=Cc(P(a,Q)),c=ic(P(a,W));a=jc(P(a,Yb));1<a&&(c+="-"+a);return["GA1",c,b][H](".")},Gc=function(a,b,c){for(var d=[],e=[],g,ca=0;ca<a[y];ca++){var l=a[ca];if(l.H[c]==b)d[p](l);else void 0==g||l.H[c]<g?(e=[l],g=l.H[c]):l.H[c]==g&&e[p](l)}return 0<d[y]?d:e},lc=function(a){return 0==a[t](".")?a.substr(1):
a},ic=function(a){return lc(a)[A](".")[y]},kc=function(a){if(!a)return"/";1<a[y]&&a.lastIndexOf("/")==a[y]-1&&(a=a.substr(0,a[y]-1));0!=a[t]("/")&&(a="/"+a);return a},jc=function(a){a=kc(a);return"/"==a?1:a[A]("/")[y]};function Xc(a,b,c){"none"==b&&(b="");var d=[],e=Ca(a);a="__utma"==a?6:2;for(var g=0;g<e[y];g++){var ca=(""+e[g])[A](".");ca[y]>=a&&d[p]({hash:ca[0],R:e[g],O:ca})}return 0==d[y]?void 0:1==d[y]?d[0]:Zc(b,d)||Zc(c,d)||Zc(null,d)||d[0]}function Zc(a,b){var c,d;null==a?c=d=1:(c=La(a),d=La(D(a,".")?a[F](1):"."+a));for(var e=0;e<b[y];e++)if(b[e][h]==c||b[e][h]==d)return b[e]};var od=new RegExp(/^https?:\/\/([^\/:]+)/),pd=/(.*)([?&#])(?:_ga=[^&#]*)(?:&?)(.*)/;function Bc(a){a=a.get(Q);var b=Ic(a,0);return"_ga=1."+K(b+"."+a)}function Ic(a,b){for(var c=new Date,d=O[oa],e=d.plugins||[],c=[a,d.userAgent,c.getTimezoneOffset(),c.getYear(),c.getDate(),c.getHours(),c.getMinutes()+b],d=0;d<e[y];++d)c[p](e[d].description);return La(c[H]("."))}var Dc=function(a){J(48);this.target=a;this.T=!1};
Dc[z].ca=function(a,b){if(a.tagName){if("a"==a.tagName[I]()){a[Ab]&&Pc(a,qd(this,a[Ab],b));return}if("form"==a.tagName[I]())return rd(this,a)}if("string"==typeof a)return qd(this,a,b)};
var qd=function(a,b,c){var d=pd.exec(b);d&&3<=d[y]&&(b=d[1]+(d[3]?d[2]+d[3]:""));a=a[jd].get("linkerParam");var e=b[t]("?"),d=b[t]("#");c?b+=(-1==d?"#":"&")+a:(c=-1==e?"?":"&",b=-1==d?b+(c+a):b[F](0,d)+c+a+b[F](d));return b},rd=function(a,b){if(b&&b[kd]){var c=a[jd].get("linkerParam")[A]("=")[1];if("get"==b.method[I]()){for(var d=b.childNodes||[],e=0;e<d[y];e++)if("_ga"==d[e][v]){d[e][id]("value",c);return}d=M[u]("input");d[id]("type","hidden");d[id]("name","_ga");d[id]("value",c);b.appendChild(d)}else"post"==
b.method[I]()&&(b.action=qd(a,b[kd]))}};
Dc[z].S=function(a,b,c){function d(c){try{c=c||O.event;var d;a:{var g=c[jd]||c.srcElement;for(c=100;g&&0<c;){if(g[Ab]&&g.nodeName[m](/^a(?:rea)?$/i)){d=g;break a}g=g.parentNode;c--}d={}}("http:"==d[E]||"https:"==d[E])&&sd(a,d[ma]||"")&&d[Ab]&&Pc(d,qd(e,d[Ab],b))}catch(w){J(26)}}var e=this;this.T||(this.T=!0,L(M,"mousedown",d,!1),L(M,"keyup",d,!1));if(c){c=function(b){b=b||O.event;if((b=b[jd]||b.srcElement)&&b[kd]){var c=b[kd][m](od);c&&sd(a,c[1])&&rd(e,b)}};for(var g=0;g<M.forms[y];g++)L(M.forms[g],
"submit",c)}};function sd(a,b){if(b==M[B][ma])return!1;for(var c=0;c<a[y];c++)if(a[c]instanceof RegExp){if(a[c][pa](b))return!0}else if(0<=b[t](a[c]))return!0;return!1};var Jd=function(a,b,c){this.U=ed;this.aa=b;(b=c)||(b=(b=P(a,V))&&"t0"!=b?Wd[pa](b)?"_gat_"+Cc(P(a,Na)):"_gat_"+Cc(b):"_gat");this.Y=b},Rd=function(a,b){var c=b.get(Wb);b.set(Wb,function(b){Pd(a,b);var d=c(b);Qd(a,b);return d});var d=b.get(Xb);b.set(Xb,function(b){var c=d(b);Id(a,b);return c})},Pd=function(a,b){b.get(a.U)||("1"==Ca(a.Y)[0]?b.set(a.U,"",!0):b.set(a.U,""+fe(),!0))},Qd=function(a,b){b.get(a.U)&&zc(a.Y,"1",b.get(Yb),b.get(W),b.get(Na),6E5)},Id=function(a,b){if(b.get(a.U)){var c=new ee,
d=function(a){$a(a).F&&c.set($a(a).F,b.get(a))};d(hb);d(ib);d(Na);d(Q);d(a.U);c.set($a(ld).F,Td(b));var e=a.aa;c.map(function(a,b){e+=K(a)+"=";e+=K(""+b)+"&"});e+="z="+fe();ta(e);b.set(a.U,"",!0)}},Wd=/^gtm\d+$/;var fd=function(a,b){var c=a.b;if(!c.get("dcLoaded")){Nd(c,29);b=b||{};var d;b[U]&&(d=Cc(b[U]));d=new Jd(c,"https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?t=dc&aip=1&_r=3&",d);Rd(d,c);c.set("dcLoaded",!0)}};var Sd=function(a){var b;b=a.get("dcLoaded")?!1:"cookie"!=a.get(ac)?!1:!0;b&&(Nd(a,51),b=new Jd(a),Pd(b,a),Qd(b,a),a.get(b.U)&&(a.set(Md,1,!0),a.set(gd,oc()+"/r/collect",!0)))};var Lc=function(){var a=O.gaGlobal=O.gaGlobal||{};return a.hid=a.hid||fe()};var ad,bd=function(a,b,c){if(!ad){var d;d=M[B][h];var e=O[v],g=/^#?gaso=([^&]*)/;if(e=(d=(d=d&&d[m](g)||e&&e[m](g))?d[1]:Ca("GASO")[0]||"")&&d[m](/^(?:!([-0-9a-z.]{1,40})!)?([-.\w]{10,1200})$/i))zc("GASO",""+d,c,b,a,0),f._udo||(f._udo=b),f._utcp||(f._utcp=c),a=e[1],wa("https://www.google.com/analytics/web/inpage/pub/inpage.js?"+(a?"prefix="+a+"&":"")+fe(),"_gasojs");ad=!0}};var wb=/^(UA|YT|MO|GP)-(\d+)-(\d+)$/,pc=function(a){function b(a,b){d.b[q].set(a,b)}function c(a,c){b(a,c);d.filters.add(a)}var d=this;this.b=new Ya;this.filters=new Ha;b(V,a[V]);b(Na,sa(a[Na]));b(U,a[U]);b(W,a[W]||xa());b(Yb,a[Yb]);b(Zb,a[Zb]);b($b,a[$b]);b(Wc,a[Wc]);b(bc,a[bc]);b(cc,a[cc]);b(Ka,a[Ka]);b(dc,a[dc]);b(ec,a[ec]);b(ac,a[ac]);b(Ad,a[Ad]);b(hb,1);b(ib,"j37");c(Qb,Ma);c(dd,cd);c(Rb,Oa);c(md,vb);c(Sb,nc);c(Uc,Yc);c(Tb,Ja);c(Vb,Ta);c(Vc,Hc);c(zd,yd);c(Ld,Sd);c(Wb,Pa);c(Xb,Sa);c(Cd,Fd(this));
Jc(this.b,a[Q]);Kc(this.b);this.b.set(jb,Lc());bd(this.b.get(Na),this.b.get(W),this.b.get(Yb))},Jc=function(a,b){if("cookie"==P(a,ac)){hc=!1;var c;b:{var d=Ca(P(a,U));if(d&&!(1>d[y])){c=[];for(var e=0;e<d[y];e++){var g;g=d[e][A](".");var ca=g.shift();("GA1"==ca||"1"==ca)&&1<g[y]?(ca=g.shift()[A]("-"),1==ca[y]&&(ca[1]="1"),ca[0]*=1,ca[1]*=1,g={H:ca,s:g[H](".")}):g=void 0;g&&c[p](g)}if(1==c[y]){J(13);c=c[0].s;break b}if(0==c[y])J(12);else{J(14);d=ic(P(a,W));c=Gc(c,d,0);if(1==c[y]){c=c[0].s;break b}d=
jc(P(a,Yb));c=Gc(c,d,1);c=c[0]&&c[0].s;break b}}c=void 0}c||(c=P(a,W),d=P(a,$b)||xa(),c=Xc("__utma",d,c),void 0!=c?(J(10),c=c.O[1]+"."+c.O[2]):c=void 0);c&&(a[q].set(Q,c),hc=!0)}c=a.get(cc);if(e=(c=M[B][c?"href":"search"][m]("(?:&|#|\\?)"+K("_ga")[Qc](/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g,"\\$1")+"=([^&#]*)"))&&2==c[y]?c[1]:"")a.get(bc)?(c=e[t]("."),-1==c?J(22):(d=e[F](c+1),"1"!=e[F](0,c)?J(22):(c=d[t]("."),-1==c?J(22):(e=d[F](0,c),c=d[F](c+1),e!=Ic(c,0)&&e!=Ic(c,-1)&&e!=Ic(c,-2)?J(23):(J(11),a[q].set(Q,
c)))))):J(21);b&&(J(9),a[q].set(Q,K(b)));a.get(Q)||((c=(c=O.gaGlobal&&O.gaGlobal.vid)&&-1!=c[ga](/^(?:utma\.)?\d+\.\d+$/)?c:void 0)?(J(17),a[q].set(Q,c)):(J(8),a[q].set(Q,[fe()^Mc()&2147483647,n.round((new Date)[da]()/1E3)][H]("."))));mc(a)},Kc=function(a){var b=O[oa],c=O.screen,d=M[B];a.set(lb,ya(a.get(ec)));if(d){var e=d.pathname||"";"/"!=e.charAt(0)&&(J(31),e="/"+e);a.set(kb,d[E]+"//"+d[ma]+e+d[ga])}c&&a.set(qb,c.width+"x"+c.height);c&&a.set(pb,c.colorDepth+"-bit");var c=M.documentElement,g=(e=
M.body)&&e[la]&&e[na],ca=[];c&&c[la]&&c[na]&&("CSS1Compat"===M.compatMode||!g)?ca=[c[la],c[na]]:g&&(ca=[e[la],e[na]]);c=0>=ca[0]||0>=ca[1]?"":ca[H]("x");a.set(rb,c);a.set(tb,fc());a.set(ob,M.characterSet||M.charset);a.set(sb,b&&"function"===typeof b.javaEnabled&&b.javaEnabled()||!1);a.set(nb,(b&&(b.language||b.browserLanguage)||"")[I]());if(d&&a.get(cc)&&(b=M[B][h])){b=b[A](/[?&#]+/);d=[];for(c=0;c<b[y];++c)(D(b[c],"utm_id")||D(b[c],"utm_campaign")||D(b[c],"utm_source")||D(b[c],"utm_medium")||D(b[c],
.....
```

I had to trim about thousand characters to avoid max characters limit.

Comment: If I go to the http version I get the minified version without popunder. I do believe there is something else on your system that is to blame for this, its not google-analytics. So beware, you may have only temporarily worked around the problem for now.

Comment: It's likely that the ISP hijacks the Google Analytics code. Attractive target since it runs on many, many pages.

Answer (score 22):

Stack Overflow doesn't do pop ads.

So either:

1. Your ISP is inserting ads into the pages it serves you.
2. Your browser (or a toolbar/extension) is inserting ads.
3. You have some other ad-ware on your computer.
4. Your router is compromised with malware that rewrites web pages you browse
5. You aren't actually on Stack Overflow, but one of several sites that scrapes our content and mimics the site - apart from the ads.

Comment: I agree with all of your "eithers" but it only happens with stackoverflow.com no other site. And I am on stackoverflow.com logged In so that removes that doubt. Perhaps its 2.

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ there could be another option I haven't thought of (or been reminded of) yet.

Comment: What would that be?

Comment: I am also getting these pop-ups, and I noticed they only happen in stackoverflow

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ - I don't know ;) With your rep you should only be getting side bar ads anyway and I've never seen any of them popup.

Comment: Would either of you be able to provide a screenshot of what this ad looks like / where it appears? Also, copy-paste the exact URL from the address bar.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/urih6o8v5/

Comment: screenshot attached...

Comment: I also noticed it doesn't happen in firefox on my computer, so it's not the ISP

Comment: @EduardoWada then it's probably the browser or an extension.

Comment: For me I've figured its JSONView that's causing it.

Comment: I disabled "Axure RP Extension for Chrome" and now it's back to normal

Comment: Although I've removed that plugin, I am still getting popups, and i am inclined to believe with Tim Post because using https:// i get rid of popups and their is no other adware on my system as all softwares are from verified publishers.

Comment: I stopped getting the pop-ups when I removed the plugin but started getting them again 2 days later, and nothing was installed in the mean time

Answer (score 7):

As ChrisF notes, these aren't coming from us. We've received reports from users who have free Internet providers (at the cost of more ads), or really *really* crappy ISPs they actually pay, yet still inject ads.

The trick in the *second* case is just use https:// when accessing the site. While you will see warnings about mixed content until we get everything working properly, going over SSL will generally bust through the caching (squid?) proxy servers these outfits use. If you're paying for Internet and your provider is still injecting ads, it's time to find a less sleazy provider.

If you're on the 'free' plan where you pay for it by viewing ads, then, well, expect to see ads :) But, they don't come from us. At most users would see two banners around the question, and one in the sidebar. Anything else isn't us.

Comment: +1 for using https, because i am now getting these popups on all non https sites...

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ If you actually _pay_ for Internet, I'd give your ISP a call and let them know just how much you don't appreciate that.

Comment: well that's the tricky part first its my employers who pay for internet and second its is the only ISP around here other than 3G so, I have to bear the burden of super annoying popups. I am still searching for any untrusted software on my system to remove :(.