# Why do we see these popups in Iran?

Tags: support, advertising, popup

I just wanted to know if it's us or everybody else is having this nonsense popups when clicking on Stack Overflow contents.

We're in Iran and on the same LAN network. When we open a Stack Overflow question and click anywhere it opens a popup from 'clickonads'. It happened every time when we open a question.

The curious case is when we change the IP address and use a proxy to access the site it won't open a popup and act normally.

We wonder if we got infected by virus or malware, or if this is normal behaviour of Stack Overflow.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292212/weird-popup-ads-from-stackoverflow-sites/292213#292213

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow doesn't serve any of those ads. They either originate from some malware program on your computer (which seems unlikely as it doesn't happen when switching your IP address), or your Internet Service Provider injects them. In the latter case, you could try to switch to HTTPS, but it is [not yet fully supported](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) by Stack Overflow.