# Has Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange started showing pop-under ads on click?

Tags: support, advertising

For *every first click* on *each page* that I open in Stack Overflow, I get a pop under opened on a new tab. So if I refresh the page, and I click on anything on that page again, a new advertising tab opened.

I'm just curious—is this an intended behaviour, or is this only experienced by me (maybe my browser or computer got worms or something)? Because this kind of advertising is very annoying, and I read somewhere that SO deeply care about the how and what advertising displayed on the site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not us. We would find that just as incredibly annoying as you. It's definitely something on your end. You're not the first person to run into a similar problem though, for example: [Weird popup ads from Stack Overflow sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292212/weird-popup-ads-from-stack-overflow-sites). There are some suggestions there for debugging.

Comment: Turns out, it was from my internet provider that start to provide pop under ads to every website that doesn't use SSL. That's why I wondering why I don't get pop under from Facebook, but get pop under from stack overflow, hence this question. But then I tried other non-SSL website, and get the same problem. Thanks for the response. I hate my internet provider.